# VIM LanguageClient and ALE interop/overlap

Tags: vim, reason

I'm a VIM user and recently started using Reason for React dev. I use ALE and LanguageClient for different languages, i.e.:

**autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim**

- rust
- ocaml
- reason

**w0rp/ale**

- python
- javascript
- reason

Note the overlap with Reason.

I seem to be in this weird place where I'm using half of the functionality of each. Specifically, ALE is running refmt for formatting code, but it's not performing linting. The LanguageClient is performing linting. I've confirmed this by commenting out refmt in ALE (breaks formatting) and commenting out the LanguageClient line for reason (breaks linting). I prefer ALE's linting over LanguageClient due to its use of quickfix (:lopen to see all the issues) and async error checking on leaving insert mode. I also seem to have redundant capabilities across both plugins right now, which just bugs my internal perfectionist.

Questions:

1. Is there any point in having both of these plugins, or is the functionality entirely duplicated between ALE and LanguageClient?
2. Why isn't linting working in ALE? Works in every other language, and OLS shows as a valid option in my :ALEInfo.

.vimrc...

Thoughts?

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" General NVIM
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

if has("nvim")
  let g:python_host_prog = '/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/neovim2/bin/python'
  let g:python3_host_prog = '/Users/nathan/.pyenv/versions/neovim3/bin/python'
endif

if has("nvim") || (v:version > 8)
  set termguicolors
  set guicursor=a:blinkon0
endif

colorscheme dark


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Plugins
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
filetype off
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

" Linting
Plug 'w0rp/ale'
Plug 'autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim', {
      \ 'branch': 'next',
      \ 'do': 'bash install.sh',
      \ }

" Completion
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' } 
Plug 'Shougo/neco-syntax'
Plug 'wokalski/autocomplete-flow', { 'for': 'javascript' }
Plug 'carlitux/deoplete-ternjs', { 'do': 'npm install -g tern', 'for': 'javascript'  }
Plug 'Shougo/neosnippet'
Plug 'zchee/deoplete-jedi'
Plug 'Shougo/neosnippet-snippets'


" General
Plug 'chriskempson/base16-vim' "Color Scheme
Plug 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim' "Fuzzy Find
Plug 'dkprice/vim-easygrep' "Instant grep across files
Plug 'easymotion/vim-easymotion' "Fast movement
Plug 'jeetsukumaran/vim-buffergator' "Buffer management
Plug 'jiangmiao/auto-pairs' "Close pairs
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle'  } "NerdTree
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary' "File-specific commenting
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround' "Handle surrounds
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline' "Airline bar
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes' "Make airline pretty
Plug '/usr/local/opt/fzf' | Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim' "Fuzzy finder
" Plug 'vim-scripts/paredit.vim', {'for': 'clojure'} "Lisp balance

" Javascript - need to be in order
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript', {'for': ['javascript', 'reason']}
Plug 'reasonml-editor/vim-reason-plus', {'for': ['reason']}
Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx', {'for': ['javascript', 'reason']}
Plug 'alvan/vim-closetag', {'for': ['html', 'vue', 'javascript', 'reason']}

" Filetype Plugins
Plug 'fatih/vim-go', {'for': 'go'}
Plug 'hdima/python-syntax', {'for': 'python'}
Plug 'jparise/vim-graphql', {'for': 'graphql'}
Plug 'neovimhaskell/haskell-vim', {'for': 'haskell'}
Plug 'rust-lang/rust.vim', {'for': 'rust'}
" Plug 'derekwyatt/vim-scala', {'for': 'scala'}
" Plug 'elixir-lang/vim-elixir', {'for': 'elixir'}
" Plug 'keith/swift.vim', {'for': 'swift'}
" Plug 'udalov/kotlin-vim', {'for': 'kotlin'}
" Plug 'guns/vim-clojure-static', {'for': 'clojure'}


call plug#end()
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
" END Plug


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" General settings
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

set autoindent "Enable automatic indentation
set backspace=indent,eol,start "Adaptive backspace
set cb=unnamed "Use global clipboard
set cc=0 "Color column (off by default, 80 for python, etc)
set copyindent "Copy indentation
set expandtab "Use spaces for tabs 
set hlsearch "Highlight search
set ignorecase "Case insensitive search
set laststatus=2 "Always show airline
set mouse=a "Respond to mouse
set noerrorbells "Don't beep
set nostartofline "Keep cursor in place when switching buffers
set novisualbell "No annoying flashing
set ruler "Adds line numbers and distance to airline
set shiftround "Tab half-indented to the next tabstop
set shiftwidth=2 "Default indentation
set shortmess+=c "Avoid unnecessary messages
set sidescrolloff=0 "Don't scroll horizontally
set smartcase "Use case in search if caps is used
set smarttab "Use semantic tabs
set softtabstop=2 "Pretend spaces are tabs
set t_vb= "Disable visual bell
set tabstop=2 "Default tab width
set vb "Disable visual bell
set wildignore=.DS_Store,node_modules,bower_components "Ignore for CtrlP
set wrap "Wrap long lines


set backupcopy=yes " Fix for bucklescript

" Fix some shiftwidths
autocmd Filetype haskell set shiftwidth=4
autocmd Filetype go set shiftwidth=4


"Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Ale (linting and error checking)
let g:ale_javascript_eslint_executable = 'eslint_d' "Faster implementation
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed="normal" "Lint on normal mode
let g:ale_reason_ols_executable = '/usr/local/bin/reason-language-server'
let g:ale_linters = {
      \ 'javascript': ['flow', 'eslint'],
      \ 'python': ['pyflakes'],
      \ 'reason': ['ols'],
      \}
let g:ale_fixers = {
      \ 'javascript': ['eslint', 'prettier'],
      \ 'reason': ['refmt'],
      \ 'python': ['autopep8'],
      \}
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1

" Airline
let g:airline_theme='bubblegum'
let g:airline#extensions#ale#enabled = 1

" Buffergator
let g:buffergator_display_regime = "parentdir"
let g:buffergator_expand_on_split = 0

" vim-javascript conceal
let g:javascript_conceal_function = "ƒ"
let g:javascript_conceal_null = "ø"
let g:javascript_conceal_this = "@"
let g:javascript_conceal_return = "⇚"
let g:javascript_conceal_arrow_function = "⇒"

let g:closetag_filenames = "*.html,*.xhtml,*.phtml,*.js,*.jsx,*.re,*.xml,*.vue"
let g:haskell_indent_in = 0
let g:NERDTreeQuitOnOpen = 1
let g:jsx_ext_required = 0
let g:javascript_plugin_flow = 1

" Match Tag Always (close HTML tags)
let g:mta_filetypes = {
      \ 'html' : 1,
      \ 'xhtml' : 1,
      \ 'xml' : 1,
      \ 'jinja' : 1,
      \ 'javascript' : 1,
      \ 'reason' : 1,
      \ 'javascript.jsx' : 1,
      \}


let g:LanguageClient_serverCommands = {
      \ 'ocaml': ['ocaml-language-server', '--stdio'],
      \ 'rust': ['rustup', 'run', 'nightly', 'rls'],
      \ 'reason': ['/usr/local/bin/reason-language-server'],
      \ }
"'python': ['/usr/local/bin/pyls'],
"'javascript': ['javascript-typescript-stdio'],


" Use Platinum Searcher Grep, CtrlP, etc
if executable('pt')
  " Use pt over grep
  set grepprg=pt\ --nogroup\ --nocolor
  " Use pt in CtrlP for listing files. Lightning fast and respects .gitignore
  let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'pt %s -l --nocolor -g ""'
  " pt is fast enough that CtrlP doesn't need to cache
  let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0
endif

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"Keyboard mappings
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let mapleader = "\<Space>"

nnoremap <Leader>[ :BuffergatorMruCyclePrev<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>] :BuffergatorMruCycleNext<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>b :BuffergatorOpen<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>c :ALEToggle<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>d :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>f :Grep<space>
nnoremap <Leader>g :CtrlPBuffer<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>h :exec &conceallevel ? "set conceallevel=0" : "set conceallevel=1"<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>j :ALENextWrap<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>k :ALEPreviousWrap<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>o :CtrlP<CR>
"nnoremap <Leader>p "+p
nnoremap <Leader>q :q<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>r :ALEFix<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>s :w<CR>
nnoremap <Leader>w <C-W><C-W>
"vnoremap <Leader>y "+y

imap jk <Esc>


" Language Client
nnoremap <silent> K :call LanguageClient#textDocument_hover()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> gd :call LanguageClient#textDocument_definition()<CR>

" Autocomplete
let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1
let g:neosnippet#enable_completed_snippet = 1
inoremap <expr><Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <S-Tab> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<S-Tab>"



"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"Fixes
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs/issues/187
autocmd VimEnter,BufEnter,BufWinEnter * silent! iunmap <buffer> <M-">


"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
"GUI stuffs
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

if has("gui_vimr")
  nnoremap <D-S-}> :tabnext<CR>
  nnoremap <D-S-{> :tabprevious<CR>
endif
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

This line in my .vimrc wasn't working:

`let g:ale_reason_ols_executable = '/usr/local/bin/reason-language-server'`

ALE tacks on the `--stdio` option, which ocaml-language-server requires. This isn't accepted by reason-language-server. It's not just ignored, but the language server doesn't run at all. I was able to get it working by creating a shell script to call reason-language-server that ignored the extra parameter. Essentially this:

```
#!/bin/bash
reason-language-server
```

With that change, ALE now lints properly, and I've removed the extra LanguageClient plugin. To the best of my knowledge ALE interacting with the reason-language-server (or ocaml-language-server) and LanguageClient provide the exact same information. They both provide whatever the language-server tells them. I don't mean to misrepresent either project, but the detail and capabilities on both plugins seems to be identical--they're just provided through a slightly different UI. Once I move rust over to ALE, I should have the same UI, hotkeys, etc, across all languages.

On the off chance either developer ever sees this SO, both projects are fantastic, and I appreciate the effort in making VIM an effective, full-featured IDE.

Comment: Please open an issue on GitHub for adding support for `reason-language-server`. You shouldn't be setting the executable of one language server to the path for another one. Instead, someone should a linter definition for `reason-language-server`, and the arguments can be defined differently.

Comment: @w0rp Opened [#2331](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/issues/2331). I'll add it myself when I have time. Thanks.